# Is there an analytic formula or good fitting function for the Hankel transform of a Sersic profile?

Tags: taylor-expansion, fourier-transform, approximate-integration

I'm trying to find an analytic form for the Hankel transform of a Sersic profile:
$$
\begin{align}
f_n(r) &= \frac{e^{-r^{1/n}}}{n \Gamma(2n)}\\
F_n(k) &= \int_0^\infty f(r) r J_0(k r) dr
\end{align}
$$

*Background*: This profile is commonly used in astronomy to model galaxy surface brightness profiles.  $n=1/2$ is a Gaussian.  $n=1$ is an exponential, which is a good fit for galaxies like the Milky Way.  $n=4$ is called a DeVaucouleurs profile and is a good fit to many very large galaxies in clusters.  Most galaxies are well fit by a Sersic profile in the range $n=1$ to $n=5$.  When drawing these galaxies, we normally draw them in Fourier space, since we need to convolve the profile by a point-spread function, which is easiest to do via multiplication in Fourier space.  Thus we generally use the Hankel transform of the profile to directly draw the $F(k)$ values for a given galaxy in our Fourier-space image.

The Hankel transform for n=4 (and higher) is fairly slow to compute, so I have been looking for an analytic formula that I might be able to use.  The two values of $n$ for which I know the answer are:
$$
\begin{align}
F_{1/2}(k) &= e^{-k^2/4}\\
F_1(k) &= (1+k^2)^{-3/2}
\end{align}
$$
The other possibly helpful bit of information I have is the MacLaurin series in general
$$
\begin{align}
F_n(k) &= 1 - \frac{1}{4} \frac{\Gamma(4n)}{\Gamma(2n)} k^2 
  + \frac{1}{64}\frac{\Gamma(6n)}{\Gamma(2n)} k^4
  - \frac{1}{2304}\frac{\Gamma(8n)}{\Gamma(2n)} k^6 + \dots \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i \Gamma(2(i+1)n)}{2^{2i} \Gamma(i+1)^2 \Gamma(2n)} k^{2i}
\end{align}
$$
Unfortunately, when $n>1$, the coefficients in the MacLaurin series get big very quickly, so its not a useful approximation unless k is very, very small.  I'm not sure formally about the radius of convergence, but practically, it diverges pretty quickly.  For instance, the series for n=4 is
$$
1 - (6.5 \times 10^7) k^2 + (8.0 \times 10^{16}) k^4 - (7.1 \times 10^{26}) k^6 + (2.7 \times 10^{37}) k^8 - \dots
$$
so it's useless above around $k=10^{-5}$.

Can anyone offer some guidance about how I might be able to find an analytic formula that has this MacLaurin series?  Or alternatively some transformation I could make to this function that would render the series expansion convergent and therefore tractable as a fitting formula?

Thanks in advance for any tips you might be able to offer.

Note: I tried using a Pade approximant to the MacLaurin series, and it extends the range of accuracy by a factor of a few, but that's about it.

Comment: I'd say a series expansion is a good idea, but perhaps use a Taylor series with an expansion point $k_0>0$ closer to where you need it. What is a typical range for $k$?

Comment: Most of the power is pretty close to k=0.  F(0) = 1, then it falls off fairly quickly, approaching a power law with index near -2.  (I think the asymptote is roughly F(k) ~ k^(-2-1/n).)  Visually, it resembles something like (1+ak^2)^-b where a gets large as n increases and b gets small.  For n=4, a=2.4e9, b=0.027 looks reasonably close, but isn't accurate enough in detail.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: you have data $(k_i,\hat{y}_i)$ with $\hat{y}_i \simeq F_n(k_i)$, for an unknown $n$. You want to estimate the value of $n$ from the data, but this is expensive because the evaluation of the function $F_n$ is costly. Therefore, one option might be to apply some kind of discrete inverse Hankel transform to the data first to obtain pairs $(r_i,y_i)$ with $y_i \simeq f_n(r_i)$, and then use $f_n$ for the fitting, which is cheap to evaluate?

Comment: No, that's not really it.  The application is more about simulating galaxies with a variety of profiles (including a range of n, but also size, shear, and brightness) where those parameters are tuned to match known distributions of these values in real data.  When we draw these galaxies we draw them in k-space, since we need to perform a convolution, so rendering in k-space makes that easy.  One of the current tall poles in this simulation is calculating $F_n(k)$.  I'm looking to speed that up.  Currently we calculate $F_n(k)$ from the Hankel transform of $f_n(r)$.